# Dual boot Ubuntu with Windows - Full hard disk is showing as a single ntfs partition though there are more partitions

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

Recently I was trying to install Ubuntu 17.10.1 on another partition of my hard disk while Windows is already installed in one partition. There are some other partitions in my hard disk too. For Ubuntu installation I have created `Unallocated Space` after the partition where Windows is installed. The partition layout from Windows Disk Management looks like this:

[image]

But from another 3rd party software I can see the `Unallocated Space` which is not shown to Disk Management:

[image]

So far so good, I didn't think this differences would be a problem during Ubuntu installation. But it was. When I tried to install Ubuntu, I found the whole hard disk is shown as a single NTFS partition:

[image]

I was a bit worried and and used live Ubuntu to make partition using Ubuntu tools. From `gparted`, I got same behavior:

[image]

When I click on the warning sign beside `/dev/sda`, it shows:

[image]

Finally, I searched for this problem online, found someone having similar problems, but those solutions didn't work and I couldn't find the exact problematic partition in my case. I executed `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` in terminal and the output is:

[image]

I am stuck here. Please, if any expert can help me in this regard.

Comment: You have activated dynamic disk in Windows. Don't install Ubuntu or in any way change the partitions except with Windows tools unless you want to risk data loss and an unavoidable unbootable Windows.

Comment: @MichaelBay Can you please tell me elaborately, how can I fix it?

Comment: According to Microsoft there's no way back but formating once dynamic disks are enabled.